# Characteristics method, an implicit solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, characteristics

I am solving the following PDE:

$$xy(u_x-u_y)=(x-y)u$$
using the characteristic curves method.

To obtain the characteristic curves I have to solve:

$$\dfrac{dx}{xy}=\dfrac{dy}{-xy}=\dfrac{du}{(x-y)u}$$

From $\dfrac{dx}{xy}=\dfrac{dy}{-xy}$ we have $x+y=c$, with $c$ a constant.Substituting in $\dfrac{dx}{xy}=\dfrac{du}{(x-y)u}$ this implies $\dfrac{du}{u}=\dfrac{(x-y)dx}{xy}=\dfrac{(2x+c)dx}{x(c-x)}$.

Integrating on both sides we have $\ln(u)=-\ln((c-x)x)+k_1$ this implies $u(x,y)=\dfrac{k}{xy}$, with $k$ constant.

But check out the solution and it says that the general solution is given by $\Phi(x+y,xyu)=0$ for any arbitrary function $\Phi$.

And then he says that in general if the solutions to the characteristic system are constant, let's say $f (x, y) = c$ and $g (x, y, u) = k$, with $k$ and $c$ constant, then the solution will be given by $\Phi(f,g)=0$, could someone explain to me why you say that please? and see if my solution is correct. Thanks

Comment: Be careful with using the same $c$ for two different constants in the same expression!

Comment: You're right @user10354138

Comment: What you have shown is that, along the curve (line) $x+y=c$, we know the solution has to look like $xyu(x,y)=k$, some constant $k$.  But the constant $k$ is allowed to vary as we change to another line $x+y=c'$. and we don't really have any control over this dependence unless we are given data on a Cauchy hypersurface.  Hence we write $\Phi(x+y,xyu)=0$ as an implicit equation for this dependence.  Similar for general case.

Comment: and how could I show that $ \Phi $ is indeed a solution to the differential equation? applying chain rule?

Comment: Yes, chain rule and eliminate $\Phi_{,1}$, $\Phi_{,2}$.

Comment: It is not very clear to me what to eliminate, but I will try, could you write this as an answer please? to give you the points, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method of characteristics, we reduce the quasilinear PDE as an ODE along characteristic curves and hence solve it for points on a characteristic curve.  But at the end of the day, we need to go back and bundle these curves together to form our solution (at least locally).

What you have therefore shown is that, along any characteristic curve, the value of $x+y$ and $xyu$ are constant.  But they are allow to change as we move to another characteristic curve (indeed, each characteristic curve is given by $\{x+y=c\}\cap\{xyu=k\}$ locally (some $(c,k)\in\mathbb{R}^2$)).  Our solution surface $(x,y,u)$ is locally a 1-parameter family of characteristic curves $(c,k)$ but we don't actually know how $c,k$ are related to each other unless we are given initial data.  In other words, we have an arbitrary freedom of reasonable (see next paragraph) parametrisation of this family $(c,k)$ as $\Phi(c,k)=0$, then we have our general solution $\Phi(x+y,xyu)=0$.

Indeed you can check $\Phi(x+y,xyu(x,y))=0$ solves the given PDE locally:  differentiating with respect to $x,y$ gives
\begin{align*}
0&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Phi(x+y,xyu)\\
&=\Phi_{,1}(x+y,xyu)+\Phi_{,2}(x+y,xyu)(yu+xyu_x)\\
0&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Phi(x+y,xyu)\\
&=\Phi_{,1}(x+y,xyu)+\Phi_{,2}(x+y,xyu)(xu+xyu_y)
\end{align*}
If $\Phi_{,2}(x+y,xyu)\neq 0$ (which you must have to say anything about $u$ since the only way for $u$ to come in is through the second slot of $\Phi$), this gives the PDE
$$
yu+xyu_x = xu+xyu_y
$$
which is just a simple rearrangement of the given PDE.  In the general case, we want $\Phi$ to be regular parametrisation (i.e., not both $\Phi_{,1}$ and $\Phi_{,2}$ vanish simultaneously when $\Phi=0$).  Similarly for higher dimensions.